# Computer wont boot with any media after installing wine on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: boot, linux-kernel, live-usb, livecd

Yup. I can boot into anything (meaning the os part), like a cd/dvd, a live usb, or the os on the HDD. 
I can boot into the first screen, which I think is called the grub selection screen and whatever else there are. But when I select something to boot. I just get a screen with a blinking line. I tried booting into a live usb of knoppix, is stops reading from the usb after saying "Booting into kernel". The other os's don't say anything. 
They all have the same result. I'm pretty sure I can't boot into a kernel at all.
I can boot into the Ultimate Boot CD and do CPU burn in, I was hoping it would get the cpu going or something.

UPDATE: on the Knoppix cd, there is a debug64. I chose that and got passed the "booting into kernel" message, then the boot stopped at "[2.444305]registered taskstats version 1".

Link to my G+ post on this matter. https://plus.google.com/107988923652678124819/posts/TbbzrrpycNQ

Comment: In grub selection menu, remove the word `quiet` to see the messages from kernel.

Comment: SHW. how, where, with what?

Comment: can you paste grub options ?

Comment: i just found out how to edit the boot commands. so i removed quiet from the normal ubuntu image. its stopped at the same point as the recovery image does. [1.859996] AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled

Comment: Alex, Ah, so it's kernel issue

Comment: but how can other kernel images on live cds and and stuff have same result.

Comment: It's strange and unusual for the kernel to stop booting without *any* message to that effect. Usually, it's the other way round: how to get the kernel to be less verbose when it encounters an issue.

Comment: well i just found out i can boot into parted magic on  the UBCD, but only the top option(all from ram). im going to reformat the HDD to ext4 or ext3. is there anything i can do from the parted magic?

Comment: Have you tried dropping into single user mode? Check the procedure in the answer of [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/101063/debian-user-is-not-in-the-sudoers-file/101068#101068) (up to step 4). Also, in reference to your G+ post, can you boot into the Windows XP you managed to install?

Comment: Joseph. yes i can. there was no problem installing or booting into XP.

Comment: So this probably rules out there being any hardware/BIOS issues. Can you drop into a Linux root shell?

Comment: Joseph i have just installed xubuntu 13.10 by having apci=off at boot. not a fix but as long as its working. im ok

Comment: Do you mean Linux used to work, but stopped working after you installed Wine? Did anything else happen around the time you installed Wine, such as a kernel upgrade? If this is a laptop, have you tried turning it off, unplugging it, removing the battery, then powering it back on?

Comment: Gilles, please look at the g+ link. and yes i have tired that.

Comment: Gilles, there wasnt any kernel upgradings.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem while installing openSUSE 13.2 on my old 32bit MSI Laptop. After GRUB screen the installer loaded the kernel and started some services until it stucks at 'AppArmor: AppArmor sha1 policy hashing enabled'.

I thought the problem was actually AppArmor and disabled it on boot with bootparameter '`apparmor=0`' (http://www.mjmwired.net/kernel/Documentation/kernel-parameters.txt). This didn't help at all. AppArmor was not loaded but the booting process still stuck after a while.

The solution was starting with some additional bootparameter I saw on Ubuntu (https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfEwE.png or https://askubuntu.com/questions/186296/what-are-the-f6-options-during-installation).

So I tried to install with bootparameters '`acpi=off noapic nolapic nodmraid nomodeset`' and that worked perfectly!

I'm not sure if all of them are nescessary, but they worked. :)